# Quick Derivative Question

Tags: calculus, derivatives, chain-rule

I came across this problem that's incredibly confusing and I have no clue if my process was correct.
So the question went as follows: "Let $f$ be an increasing function with $f(0) = 3$. The derivative of $f$ is given by $f'(x)=\cos(\pi x)+x^4+6$."

So I was then asked the following: "let $g$ be the function defined by $g(x) = f(\sqrt{2x^2+7}))$. Find $g'(3)$."

So I thought the correct way to go about this way by substituting the $\sqrt{2x^2+7}$ for $x$ in the original equation for $f(x)$, but I'm not all that sure. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The problem is that you aren't given an equation for $f(x)$! (otherwise that would be a valid approach) What about the Chain Rule?

Comment: $g(x)=f(p(x))$,  so $g^\prime(x) = f^\prime(p) p^\prime(x).$

Comment: Ok, I think I'm starting to understand, so would I find the answer by using Chain Rule?

Comment: Check your tags to make sure all the tags are appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compute the antiderivative of $f$. Also, you even know the corresponding constant in the antiderivative, you can find it using the condition $f(0) = 3$. After that it's not difficult to write the formula for $g(x)$, take its derivative and calculate $g^{'}(3)$.

One more to solve it is to use chain rule, say that $t = \sqrt{2 x^2 + 7}$, then $g(x) = f(t(x))$ and $g^{'}(x) = f^{'}(t) \, t^{'}(x)$

Comment: Gotcha, so looks like I'm getting an answer of $16.8$ after using this process, does that seem like a reasonable answer?

Comment: Mm, I'd say it's too large, but it's difficult to say exacytly without making the calculations myself

Comment: Yeah it was too large, I tried to use the actual chain rule for this instead of using your equation, and yours gave me a much more reasonable answer.